# How to identify “cluster transfer” in a panel dataset?

Tags: stata, panel-data

I'm running a `xtreg, fe cluster` command on a panel dataset. The panel is constituted by thousands of firms. Panel id is defined as `nfid` and time id is `year`. Data structure is like

```
nfid year REvalue localcode
20 1998 . 1101
20 1999 . 1101
20 2000 . 1101
21 2003 . 4514
21 2004 . 4514
22 1998 . 1404
22 1999 . 1404
22 2000 . 1404
22 2001 0 1404
22 2002 0 1404
22 2003 0 1404
24 2006 0 3301
24 2007 0 3301
25 1998 . 3213
25 1999 . 3213
25 2000 . 3213
26 2006 0 1502
26 2007 0 1502
27 1998 . 4419
28 2001 0 3101
28 2002 0 3101
```

The `localcode` is code of city where the firm located, and we want to cluster the standard error on it. Generally speaking, a firm will not change its registered location during the sample period. However, in some cases, firms do experience transfer from one location to the another, which I call "cluster transfer" (maybe a little bit ambiguous), perhaps because of typos or measurement errors.

In this case, when we use the `xtreg, fe cluster(localcode)`, it will produce error message:

```
panels are not nested within clusters
```

What I want is to identify these "exotic" firms, and decide whether I can delete them safely, and then use the `cluster()` option correctly. The problem is that I cannot use `duplicates list nfid localcode`, since there are many `nfid-localcode` duplicates, and they are ok for us as long as firms do not jump from one cluster to the other. How can I distinguish the problematic ones from the normal ones?

Comment: This sounds like an existing FAQ: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/listing-observations-in-group/

Comment: Please close your previous Stata question with comments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527144/how-to-determine-complex-panel-pattern

Comment: OK，maybe I miss the FAQ for I don't choose the right key word. Sorrry for that.

Answer (score 0):

A second method from @NickCox FAQ would be to use the duplicates command:

```
keep nfid localcode
duplicates drop

* identify the exotic firms
duplicates tag nfid, gen(tag)

* print a list of exotic firm IDs:
list nfid if tag
```